# How to properly use react-native-startup-time?

Tags: reactjs, react-native

I am doing an npm expo project in vscode, for android only. Very small project. I only need to see how much time does it take for android phone to start that app. Not build time. Meaning, time between clicking to app and app opens.

There's this package: https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-native-startup-time

But it has so bad documentation. I tried to:

```
a=getTimeSinceStartup()

console.log(a)
```

```
a=StartupTime

console.log(a)
```

Both returned null. I added imports, and the code he wanted with these. Nothing works. How do you just do an app that just shows startup time?